# MySQL trigger in Cluster returns error

Tags: mysql, triggers, cluster-computing

I have  a **trigger** to perform updates when a new row inserted into another table.

The trigger is:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger child_price_update
after insert on child
for each row
BEGIN
UPDATE `amd_smpp_gw`.`MT`
SET `amd_smpp_gw`.`MT`.`child_price`=NEW.child_price
WHERE `amd_smpp_gw`.`MT`.`msg_id` = NEW.msg_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After the insert into table **"child"** (child_db database) this trigger perform an update to table MT in another database (amd_smpp_gw) and returns error:

**ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 0 'No error' from NDBCLUSTER**

What can i do to resolve this issue?

What is the reason that Cluster returns me this error when the trigger performing the update after the insert?

P.S
Updates are succesfull.

Thanks

Comment: check this link once http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,572138,572138

Comment: Thanks for the link vidyadhar.